# Angular factory gets iterated dozens of times

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-factory

In my Angular app I have a factory called `AuthFactory`.
So far I am injecting this AuthFactory in one `.run` block within my application, and four separate controllers - three of which are controllers which are bound to directives (their names and functions, I assume, are not important for my question).

Within this factory I have the following function:

```
function hasAccess(operation, clearance) {
    console.log(operation);
    console.log(clearance);
    var userPermissions = $localStorage.userPermissions;
    return userPermissions[operation] > SECURITY[clearance];
}
```

which gets returned as part of the factory instance, as follows:

```
    var service = {
        login: login,
        hasAccess: hasAccess,
        isAuthenticated: isAuthenticated,
        isAuthorized: isAuthorized,
        logout: logout,
        passwordReset: passwordReset,
        getUserPermissions: getUserPermissions
    };
```

Now to the point: I added the `console.log` statements you saw before to test whether or not the parameters were being passed correctly. However, these statements get logged well over 50 times in my console (I didn't count but it does come to a stop, and it is not an infinite cycle error - you can see a small example in the screenshot below). This seems incredibly inefficient.

[image]

Is this normal behavior in an Angular application?
If not, what could I do to debug this and effectively reduce the excessive number of times this factory is called.

---

Here is the code of one of the directives from where this factory is being called, in case it helps:

http://pastebin.com/N2AYCJRg

Comment: What is returned from the factory itself (the base return of the factory function)? Also, where is the hasAccess function called?

Comment: It would be injected for each directive that uses it so if you have multiple on the page then it would be injected multiple times.

Comment: @ryan0319 the hasAccess function is called on an ng-if within the template of the directive I posted (peachSidebar)

Comment: Yeah I would be under the impression that you are calling the function that many times. You must remember it will be called every time it is rendered, and every time all the parents are rendered.